# how do I install a new KDE theme?

Tags: themes, kde

I have been trying out KDE in Ubuntu 12.04 recently, and have downloaded a few themes from KDE-LOOK.ORG but I have no idea how to change the theme?

I can select a theme from the inbuilt repo from the settings, but how do I apply a theme that I have downloaded from the KDE-LOOK site (This for example http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Amakage?content=150285), any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Go to System settings -> Application appearance (or Workspace appearance).

In some items (Colors, Icons, etc) you have the option to:

- Get new (you can search in a dialog box)
- Import (search a downloaded file and install it)

In other items (Style):

- If it's in the repositories: use synaptics (or similar)
- If it isn't in ther repositories: see if there's a PPA and use it

There are other situations that involve compiling a theme, but that's a longer story.

Answer (score 2):

in `xubuntu 18.04` and `Qt5` you should

```
sudo apt install qt5ct qt5-style-plugins
```

and add in your `.bashrc`

```
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=qt5ct
```

then run `qt5rc` and change the theme

Answer (score 0):

Install the Theme/Style by either extracting and compiling it, or installing an RPM.
Open the KDE-Menu and start the Control Center.
Select "Look and Feel".
Select "Style" if the package you installed was a style, or select "Theme Manager" if the package you installed was a theme.
Select your theme or style.
Click "Apply"
Have fun! :-)

Comment: im using ubuntu why would i install an RPM? also when extracted there isn't anything to compile as far as I can tell, I'm not sure you understand what I'm asking

Comment: You don't have to download anything from kde look.. the themes can be downloaded and installed from within the os from what I can recall... I had posted the official install instructions as per kde look...

Comment: a lot of them can be yes, but the want I want, which I have linked to cannot be, it does show in the theme manager, but when you click install it redirects to kde-look.org to download manually. is there no folder like .themes for gnome that KDE would use?